# Getting 2560x1600 out of an ATI Radeon HD 4670 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, resolution

Greetings,

I've got a Dell Studio XPS 1640 laptop (with an ATI Radeon HD 4670 graphics card) running Windows 7, and just bought a Dell 3007HPC 30-inch monitor for it. I'm trying to figure out how to get the full 2560x1600 experience out of this setup.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Plug in using an HDMI cable and an HDMI-->D-DVI converter on the monitor side.
- Open up Screen Resolution. Maximum supported setting is 1920x1080.
- Tried that (several times) - sometimes it doesn't work at all (blank screen); other times, it only shows the first 1280x800 pixels on the bigger screen.
- Tried using the Catalyst control center - played with various settings there, couldn't get the screen to show anything interesting.
- Tried using [PowerStrip](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) to set a custom resolution, again, no luck.
- Spoke to a Dell Preferred Custom Support guy for about an hour before giving up. He remote-accessed my computer, and told me that (1) The maximum supported resolution for XPS 1640 is 1920x1080, and (2) 'it seems to be working from where he sees it, must be a connection issue'.

None of this has helped.  Does anybody have ideas? Should I be using a different cable set up? Am I using Powerstrip wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> Plug in using an HDMI cable and an HDMI-->D-DVI converter on the monitor side.
> Open up Screen Resolution. Maximum supported setting is 1920x1080.

The 4670 [supports an output resolution](http://web.archive.org/web/20131107004651/http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-4000/hd-4600/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-4600-specifications.aspx) of upto 1920x1080 using the HDMI output, which is what you're getting.

> **HDMI output support**
>
> Supports all display resolutions up to 1920x1080

Comment: I thought it was something like this, but didn't want to waste time looking on google to see :)

Comment: I did exactly what you propose, and the 1920x1080 just isn't happening (see above).  Though, at this point, 1920x1080 would be nice.

Comment: @Alexey - have you tried the usuals - update driver to latest version ?

Answer (score 1):

Does you laptop have a DisplayPort output?  That may be able to output 2560x1600 - and Dell sells a [DisplayPort to dual DVI adapter](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/cables/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=330-5521).

Comment: shf, thanks! Thinking of buying this, but before I do: how do I verify that DisplayPort, in this instance, will be happy to go to 2560x1600?

Answer (score 0):

Any resolution above 1920.1200 requires a "dual" dvi cable.  (It's a cable with "extra" pins.)

Of course, your video card must support this connection.  Your monitor does.

Cheers, PW.

P.S.  A couple of years ago, the Dell sites featuring 2560.1600 monitors displayed this requirement in bold text.